# Unable to rename or delete file in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu

I am very new to eclipse, and within a project I am trying to rename/delete a file. Running eclipse under ubuntu, I right-click on a file in the 'Project Explorer' windows, and a zillion of possibilities pop up. But when I use 'delete' or 'rename' on this file, noting happens. Neither can I rename the file, nor can I delete it.

Is this a bug or a feature? How can I rename or delete a file from within eclipse? Why does it not work?

P.S. I am also not able to delete a project the same way. How to delete an eclipse project?

Comment: Is it one particular file, or *all* files that can't be renamed or deleted? Which version of Eclipse is it?

Comment: It seem to be all of the files, and the eclipse version might be 4.4.0.

Answer (score 0):

Check permission of project directory. if you don't haven't write permission this could happen try to run below command in terminal for project directory it will give read write permission to all users.

```
chmod 777 -R "yourprojcetdir"
```

Comment: Despite the fact that eclipse really seems to be incredible 'stupid' not to take care of such things automatically, your suggestion does not work. I checked the directories and files, they are all writeable by all users. Maybe I need to restart eclipse?